# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') React when calling a function that sets an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, error-handling

I am having an issue with one of my functions that takes in a Json file, and then based on the key, run a specific function. That function consists of an array and the code is here:

```
    Object.entries(objJson).forEach(([key, val]) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      val = unConvertJSON(val)
      if (key.startsWith('item1')) {
        const index = parseInt(key.charAt(key.length - 1), 10)
        setItem1(prevArray => {
          const newItemArray = prevArray.slice()
          if (Array.isArray(newItemArray)) {
            newItemArray[index - 1].push(key)
            newItemArray[index - 1].sort()
            return newItemArray
          }
        })
......
```

I made sure to check if newItemArray is indeed an array by adding if (Array.isArray(newItemArray)) then proceeding to push the value from the json file into the array.

I am getting this error message:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at networking.js:137:37
    at Po (react-dom.production.min.js:169:46)
    at Fo (react-dom.production.min.js:170:451)
    at Object.useState (react-dom.production.min.js:186:528)
    at t.useState (react.production.min.js:25:394)
```

I am using gatsby by the way and weirtdly enough when I run gatsby develop the function works perfectly fine, but when I do a gatsby build and then gatsby serve to test the build folder I get the error and then the page goes blank.

Any suggestions or comments is appreciated thanks!

Comment: can you paste a ``console.log`` of  ``newItemArray``

Comment: @MiguelHidalgo 

newItemArray: ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
networking.js:126 newItemArray: VcTransPostPass1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
networking.js:126 newItemArray: VcTransPostPass1,,VcTransPostPass2,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: In order to work ``newItemArray[index - 1].push(key)`` as expected ``newItemArray`` should have this structure ``[[],[]]``

Comment: So the problem was in the Json file as the key value pair was pointing to the wrong datatype.